# Finding the length of the public key

Tags: java, jce, jca

I'm trying to find the length of a DSA public key but it can't find the method `.length`, I've made sure I have the right  imports but it doesn't seem to work.  The snippet is  below, is there a special function to find this?

```
 //my imports 
  import java.util.*;       
  import java.io.*;                         
  import javax.crypto.*;                        
  import javax.crypto.spec.*;
  import java.security.*;

public boolean SelObj(int k, PublicKey c) throws java.rmi.RemoteException{
    for(int j =1; j<c.bitLength(); ++j) {
        //some code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The bit length of the byte array encoding:

```
c.getEncoded().length * Byte.SIZE
```

The bit length of the integer value:

```
import java.security.interfaces.DSAPublicKey

((DSAPublicKey) c).getY().bitLength()
```